# Appending an incremental column to an empty dataframe in spark java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I have an empty dataframe df2. i have created a schema for it. A string column and an auto incremental column for joining purpose with other dataframes.

```
    {
    JavaRDD<Row> rdd2=null;

   rdd2=df2.javaRDD().zipWithUniqueId().map(new Function<Tuple2<Row,Long>, Row>() {


               @Override

                public Row call(Tuple2<Row, Long> v1) throws Exception {
                    Long v2=v1._2.longValue()+1L;       
                     return RowFactory.create(v2, v1._1().getString(0));
                }
        });

            List<StructField> structFields = new ArrayList<StructField>();
            StructField structField1 = DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.LongType, false);
            StructField structField2 = DataTypes.createStructField("Description", DataTypes.StringType, true);
            structFields.add(structField1);
            structFields.add(structField2);
            StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(structFields);
            DataSet<Row> df4=objSql.createDataFrame(rdd2, schema);
            df4.show();
```

I am getting like this

+---+-----------+
| id|Description|
+---+-----------+
+---+-----------+

i need incremented value 1 for id column. Please some one help me out

Comment: String column is Description and unique id column is id. I need id column value 1 for joining with another dataframe on id.

Comment: any one please help me out of this.... I am using spark 2.0 and java 1.8